# Is there any method to overcome the memory exceed error in createview query in mongo database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My createView query includes stages such as $sort, $group with the expanding of the parent collection the view produces an error of "Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes", and when the sort issue is fixed it gives the error "Exceeded memory limit for $group", cannot use "allowdisktrue" since it is not support for createView and cannot move to the aggregation method since the view should be updated automatically parallel to the parent collection.
If anyone know a solution for memory exceed error in createView query please help me to sort out this,

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I tried a solution from my code, since the crashed view due to memory exceed can be view using a query like this, db.myView.aggregate([], { allowDiskUse: true });. so I applied this part { allowDiskUse: true }  to the query in code where I get data from that crashed view. data will be retrieved without any issue then.